# LookAT but with UI Element in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to ask if you could use a function or the same function of LookAt from unity but with a UI element.

Since the LookAt calls for a transform and the UI element is Rectransform, this seems to cause problems.

I use this because I use a world canvas and I want the camera to be able to look at that positioned world canvas.

What I want to achieve in the end is that when the user presses a button that is located on a world canvas, the player's camera points to this button that has been pressed as with lerp. and then it zooms in. I just want an idea for what to do the lookAT.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I believe this may help you:

```
// Call it on your World Canvas you want to rotate towards user's camera
// Sure thing you can replace your `Update` method to anything else to apply on action
void Update()
{
    // you can put reference to any other camera than `main`
    transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, I'm not sorry, it's the other way around, I want the camera to focus on the button. That is, if in a full view the button is in a corner, when you press the button the camera turns to see that button automatically.